# Metaclass creation string name in Python 2 supporting 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Which is the correct way to translate the following to be ready for Python 3?

```
type('Name', (object, ), {})
```

In principle this line remains the same, but as I'm using Django I started adding the following line to all my files, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/python3/#unicode-literals):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

so that I have

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals 
type('Name', (object, ), {})
```

which in turn gives

```
TypeError: type() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

The following works

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals 
type(str('Name'), (object, ), {})
```

but I'm pretty sure it doesn't make sense. Which is the correct way to deal with it?

Comment: Best not to use `unicode_literals` perhaps? `u'...'` works correctly in Python 2 and 3, for all those actual unicode literals.

Comment: Why would you want to use the low level `type('Name', (object, ), {})` instead of defining a real `class`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've edited the question to explain that `unicode_literals` was suggested in Django documentation

Comment: @poke this example is squeezed out from a scenario where I want/need to use `type` to create a class

Comment: @andrea.ge: If you target 3.3 and up only, you've found a good reason not to use `unicode_literals`, at least not for that specific module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I started using `unicode_literals` because I was forgetting to write `u''` instead of `''` more than often, so I stuck to the latter and used `''` everywere. I'm still using Python 2.7: if I remove `unicode_literals` now, would I need to replace `''` with `u''` everywhere else in that file?

Comment: @andrea.ge: yes, everyhere you want a unicode literal, you'd use `u''` instead. Consider moving the `type()` call to a utility function in a separate module if that's too painful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There are different options, but it seems that in the end I'll need to clean the code when I'll move from 2.7 to 3.x, be it remove `str()` or `u''` leftovers (not mandatory in Python >=3.3) or `if PY2 else`

Answer (score 2):

Check out  [the Python Bilingual QuickRef](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PortingToPy3k/BilingualQuickRef#metaclasses) . It seems you are doing the right thing, they also use the `str('ClassName')` construct.

Comment: This is just "one of those situations" in which the py2 vs py3 interpretation of string contents and literals do not have a clean, concise mapping. (Other examples are py3 allowing unicode class names, but py2 not, and the lack of `ur'raw unicode'` literals in py3.) As @greschd says, explicit casting to `str` is probably the best thing you can do to have cross-compatible code.